# C++ Recursion problems <confused>

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, search

I am working on understanding recursion, and I think I have it down alright... I'm trying to build a search function (like the std::string.find()) that searches a given string for another string for example:

> Given (big) string:   "ru the running cat"
>
> search (small) string: "run"

I'm trying to return a index for the where the word i am searching for (in the case above it would be **7) the recursive method i have is as follows - i can't seem to get it to return the index properly.

### calling the recursive function:

```
index = index_of(imput.c_str(), search.c_str())
```

### Recursion method:

```
int index_of( const char * i, const char * s) {
 int j;
 if (*s == '\0') { return; }
 if (*i == '\0') {
  return NULL;
 }
 else if ( *i == *s ) {
  index_of((i++), (s++));
 }
 else {
  j += index_of((i++), s);
 }
 return j;
}
```

another foreseeable problem is that when (like in the example - OK it sucks but i need one that worked) it reaches the "ru_" it's still stuck on the ' ' (SPACE) -> how would i get it to 'reset' the s pointer?

Comment: First of all, rename int i to int j (or whatever) - you have already had const char* i !

Comment: good catch i didn't even notice that ( int i -> j )

Comment: What value does the first `if` statement return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **Don't change any state variables.**  Your code should not include the operator `++` *anywhere*.  You are not trying to loop over a datastructure and change your local variables in some fashion - you are trying to generate an entirely new but smaller problem each time.  So, all those `++` operators - whether pre or post increment - are red flags.
2. **You have more than one sub-problem.** (...so single function recursion isn't ideal).

   Let's look at this systematically.

   Assume you have a working `index_of` and you just want to call it with input that's shorter than yours, and that both haystack and needle aren't empty yet.  Then one of two things may be:

   - The haystack starts with the same letter as the needle, and you just need to look a little deeper to verify this.
      *- What happens if verification succeeds - what if it fails? is this an `index_of` subproblem?*
   - ...or the haystack starts off wrong, and you need to look deeper. 
      *- Is looking deeper into the haystack an index_of subproblem?*

   Notice that if the haystack *starts* OK it doesn't necessarily mean that it starts with the *full* search string - and if it starts OK but does *not* start with the full search string, you really don't need to continue looking.  That means that the "starts-with" sub-problem is fundamentally different than the index-of sub-problem:

   - **index_of**: here, failure to find the search string at index 0 means you need to look further.
   - **starts_with**: here, failure to find the search string at index 0 means you need to stop.

   It is *possible* to say `startswith(haystack, needle):= 0==index_of(haystack, needle)`, but obviously `index_of` is a more complicated problem with a more expensive solution - so you shouldn't do that; it's also more confusing at first.
3. **Identify your base cases** - When either needle or haystack are empty, what does that mean?
4. Good names help clarify things, and recursion is hard to read at the best of times - Yacoby's reply for instance has some meaningful choices here.

### Summary

I'm not going to solve your own puzzle for you, but a few tips in recap...

- Avoid changing your local variables: you're trying to define a subproblem and then just call the right function for those newer, shorter parameters.  Don't use side-effects, they make things terribly complex.
- Recursion doesn't necessarily mean just one function `A` calling `A` - it can be any cyclic call graph that eventually terminates; you may use more functions
- If needle and haystack start with the same letter, that doesn't mean that the entire needle is at the start of the haystack - and if it is not, you still need to continue searching
- This line is wrong: `if (*s == '\0') { return 1; }`

Comment: With out using the `++` operator how am i supposed to increment the pointer? GREAT EXPLANATION thank you!

Comment: Don't "increment" the pointer - pass a *new* pointer representing a substring - i.e. something similar to this:  *if-not-found-here:* `return index_of(haystack+1, needle);`

Comment: BTW, something "similar-to-this" would return the incorrect index; you still need logic to compute that to compensate for the different string position and the possibility no index is found...

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it, which is simplify everything by moving it into different functions. Untested but it should hopefully give you an idea.

```
/**
 * Checks if one string starts with another string. This returns an
 * incorrect result if it is called where prefix is an empty string.
 */
bool starts_with_impl(const char* haystack, const char* prefix) {
    if ( *prefix == 0 ){ 
        //reached the end of prefix without having found a difference in characters
        return true;
    }else if ( *haystack == 0 || *prefix != *haystack ){
        //either prefix is longer than haystack or there is a difference in characters.
        return false;
    }
    //move along the haystack and prefix by one character
    return starts_with_impl(++haystack, ++prefix);
}
/**
 * Wrapper around starts_with_impl that returns false if prefix is an empty string
 */
bool starts_with(const char* haystack, const char* prefix) {
    return *prefix ? starts_with_impl(haystack, prefix) : false;
}

int get_substr_impl(const char* haystack, const char* const needle, int index) {
    if ( *haystack == 0 ){
        //reached the end of haystack with no match, -1 is no string found
        return -1;
    }else if ( starts_with(haystack, needle) ){
        //we have found a substring match.
        return index;
    }
    //move along haystack by one character
    return get_substr_impl(++haystack, needle, ++index);
}
/**
 * Wrapper function for the above to hide the fact we need an additional argument.
 * I am avoiding using a default argument as it makes a messy api
 */
int get_substr(const char* haystack, const char* const needle) {
    return get_substr_impl(haystack, needle, 0);
}
```

**From the comments**

> you've got 2 const's in the get_substr_impl method....

Intentional.

```
// means that the data is constant, in other words I can't change the value of needle
const char* needle;

//means that as well as the data being constant 
//I can't change the address that the pointer points to.
const char* const needle;
```

> from the main method wouldn't i just call teh get_substr_impl with the same parameters given in get_substr?

I split it as `get_substr_impl` has an additional (required) argument `int index` that is required for the inner workings of the function and should always start at 0. While you could call `get_substr_impl("abc", "a", 0);`, it looks nicer and is more understandable to call `get_substr("abc", "a");` and it avoids errors (like calling `get_substr_impl("abc", "a", 1);`)

Comment: you've got 2 `const`'s in the `get_substr_impl` method.... and where did *other come from/goto? --- and from the `main` method wouldn't i just call teh get_substr_impl with the same prameters given in `get_substr`? --- would that be for error handling?

Comment: @Eamon if needle is a pointer to `\0` it will return -1, if needle is `0` then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: All strings start with the empty string.

Comment: Great parameter names indeed, btw.  Clear names are half the work :-) - I'll use those too!

Comment: @Eamon you were right about the issues with an empty `needle`, all code has been run through a compiler, so should be far more correct.

Comment: The `needle` and `haystack` parameter names were one of the things I really liked about PHP (Which is where I stole them from ;))

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have two `i`s in your code.  That shouldn't even compile.

Also, `index_of((i++), (s++));` is effectively the same as:

```
index_of(i, s); 
++i;
++s;
```

In other words, you calling index_of over & over with the same parameters it was called with the first time. (it'll never return to get to the ++i).

Also, purely stylistic, but since the return type is an int, you should return 0, and save NULL for use with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are using post-increment, and result of (i++) is i . You have to use ++i